# RavenDB IIS authentication/authorization

Tags: ravendb

I have a scenario that should be possible with RavenDB imho but I can't find any piece of information that could help me to implement this.

I've deployed the RavenDB as IIS application to my regular hosting. I have no dedicated server so this is almost all options I have. Another option is to create web application with embedded RavenDB which I think is more complicated and I want to keep things simple now. Having RavenDB as IIS application seems to be very handy.

I want some users to be able to log in into RavenDB application and edit documents. Other users (anonymous) can only read the data.

I found that there are 2 optional bundles in the app:
Raven.Bundles.Authentication.dll
Raven.Bundles.Authorization.dll
Unfortunately the documentation on this bundles is not complete enough :(

Here is a description of what I'm aiming for: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS4UMp12PZM&feature=player_detailpage#t=899s

So the questions are:

- How can I store user information in RavenDB and authenticate against this
  information?
- How can I grant edit rights on document collections for specific users?
- How can I grant all (admin) rights to some specific user?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a few resource that you can follow:

Authentication options with RavenDB
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS4UMp12PZM

Authorization Bundle
http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/authorization
http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/authorization-bundle-design

**Edit**
For simple cases, use [application users instead of database users](http://ayende.com/blog/121857/system-users-and-application-users).
Store a `User` entities and authenticate the users against it. Each user should have a user type property which says what permissions that have. Than control what action a user can do in the application level, not in the database level.

Comment: Thanks, Fitzchak, but I've already been there :) "Authentication options with RavenDB" video gives some hints but it doesn't have answers or suitable code samples.

"Authorization Bundle" document covers more complex examples and doesn't help with simple ones. I assume that my case may be simple for anybody who is familiar with NoSQL databases but not for me.

Comment: Here is my case example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS4UMp12PZM&feature=player_detailpage#t=899s (at 14:59)

Comment: > Than control what action a user can do in the application level, not in the database level.
I have no "application level". Naked DB is available via HTTP REST. All I want is restrict access to the DB for consumers - mobile application and web sites. In case of mobile application it is in the "hands of enemy" so I can't put any "secret" password. But what I can do is authenticate mobile application users.

The beauty of RavenDB running as IIS application is that I can start using it for the prototype applications and then create some "application layer" when I will be sure about what I need.

Comment: But maybe you right, "application level" isn't that difficult to maintain. I just want to keep changes to data scheme as cheap as possible for prototyping purposes.